# Error when upgrading PyTorch to 0.3.0

Tags: pytorch

I tried to update PyTorch to the recently released 0.3.0,

```
conda install pytorch=0.3.0 torchvision -c pytorch
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
NoPackagesFoundError: Dependency missing in current linux-64 channels:
 - pytorch 0.3.0* -> mkl >=2018
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also update the condo itself and then try again:

`conda update conda
conda update pytorch -c pytorch`

It will use the updated channels and download the latest mil version.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using miniconda, `mkl` is coming from the defaults channels. To update it to `2018`, install it from the anaconda channel:

```
conda install mkl -c anaconda
```